# Should the Highlighted "was" in this sentence be "were" instead?

Tags: tense, verbs

Should the Highlighted "was" in this sentence be "were" instead?

> So the rules assigning each kind of virus to a given safety level were laxer than some might think **was** prudent.

Comment: A somewhat simpler context which embodies *exactly* the same issue regarding singular/plural verb: *The knives **are** sharper than I think **is** necessary* (or even just *They're sharper than **is** necessary*). I certainly wouldn't want to say the second highlighted verb there ***must*** be singular, but idiomatically I'm pretty sure most native speakers would prefer that to *The knives **are** sharper than I think **are** necessary*. At the end of the day, this is a fairly obscure point that's more a matter of "stylistic choice" rather than being logically / semantically "correct".

Comment: @Lambie: Your rephrased version doesn't mean the same as the original.In fact, I'm not sure it even makes sense at all.

Comment: Some might think it imprudent that the rules assigning each kind of virus to a given safety level were laxer. The so is "de trop".

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you're wondering if it should be "was" or "were" because you have a plural noun, "rules". If the verb related to this noun, you would say "the *rule was..*" or "the *rules were...*". But that isn't the case in your example.

In your sentence, the verb relates to *the degree of care* with which safety levels were assigned (it is described as "lax"), and that 'degree of care' is **singular**, so you should use "was".

Comment: How is it relevant that "degree of care" is singular? It's just a noun phrase that you've invented to justify using a singular verb, but nothing like that appears in the actual text being analysed here. One might as well say that because *the **pains** that **were** taken [to apply the rules]* is plural, that justifies using the plural verb in OP's exact example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I haven't 'invented a phrase'... I've used the English language to explain something. That's what we do here. "The rules were laxer than some might consider prudent" suggests that there is a fixed level, above which is prudent, below which is lax. It is that degree to which the verb relates.

Answer (score 0):

The business about ***some might think*** is unnecessarily distracting and syntactically irrelevant. [Here's a chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are%20greater%20than%20is%2Care%20greater%20than%20are&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) showing relative frequency for the simplest phrasing I can think of in this area....

[image]

My guess is that native speakers who *don't* think about it are the ones primarily responsible for promoting the singular usage here, because I can't think of any logical or syntactic / semantic justification for it.

All I can say is that as a native speaker myself, I'd normally prefer the singular verb form - as do many others. And presumably that preference is in reality fairly strong, since I assume it's got little to support it apart from "idiomatically established" (which somehow holds its own against grammarians and pedants! :)

Comment: What you "prefer" as a native speaker is irrelevant. The verb refers to a singular thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi! I upvoted your good answer! Now, we counterbalance the downvote! Your good answer does not deserve a downvote!